# React native with Genymontion throwing concurrent Exception

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I have basic react native application and trying to run in Genymon.
At moment I'm getting error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException:: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require(http://10.0.3.2:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev-true
```

I working on Mac with El capitan with all configuration suggested by Facebook for android dep,

I running compilation:

```
../node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js run-android
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have index.android.js file in your project?

Comment: This is simple app from facebook samples

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this problem too. Tried running `react-native run-android`

Comment: I don't see any reason why I have to install reactive native as global npm package

Comment: Also I try global but with same results and this is basic application wiith only init

Comment: I've tried using `"react-native": "~0.21.0"` in package.json. Works fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted problem. I thought problem was Genymontion but seems like there is simple explanation to forward port for android before starting react-native app

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using Genymotion, because you shouldn't need to `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` on a simulator. You'll only need to do that if you're debugging on an android device.

Comment: Yep I'm sure 100% and seems to be working on physical as on Geymontion

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me. I'm getting the same error with Genymotion and the stock Google emulator as well as on a physical android device (Samsung 4S).. I'll have to open another issue for this since it is more general

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dev Setting.

Go to Debug server host & port for device.

Type this IP address and port ==> `0.0.0.0:8081`

Reload js.

Answer (score -2):

I met same issue, please try to remove 'use strict'; in your javascript file, it should be ok.