# React native Android SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'key'

Tags: java, android, adb, react-native, genymotion

I get the following error on Emulators (tested Genymotion and google Stock Emulator) and on a physical device (Samsung S4) after running `react-native run-android`:

[image]

The error typed out:

`java.util.concurrent.ExcecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'key'. (http://192.168.50.37:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false:72450)`

- In [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133563/react-native-with-genymontion-throwing-concurrent-exception) a similar error (also an `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`) occurred with Genymotion but the solution there didn't help me, i.e. `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`.
- I also tried changing Dev Settings/`Debug server host & port for device` to `0.0.0.0:8081` instead of `MY_IP:8081`, where `MY_IP` is the IP of my PC.

I'm running react native 0.22.2

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was: `key` was defined twice in a view somewhere, i.e. something like

```
<View key={index} key={other} ... />
```

So just remove one of the `key` properties.

Intermediate step to find the solution:

At first, when pressing `Start Chrome Debugging` in the React Native Menu, the app will run again, but the error will be shown in the console of the corresponding browser tab.
Then it shows a bit better error message.

Strangely this error doesn't occur on iOS.

Comment: What method did you use to find the duplicate key?

I think I have a duplicate key in a 3rd party library and I have no idea how to identify which one.  Searching a hundred node_modules is not fun. 

Ideas anyone?

Comment: Not exactly sure anymore, I think I just went through the components I worked with prior to the bug and searched for `key`. However, a regular expression to find `key` at least twice within `< />` might help in this case?! Although your error could of course also have another cause..

Comment: **Surely** there is some kind of **lint utilities** that can catch stuff like this?
I guess Android is sort of like react-native lint.  Except it does not identify the *location* of the problem.  This time I found the redefined property inside a JSX component definition.  I have also had them in stylesheet style definitions.  I miss real compilers.

Comment: You can use this regular expression with ack in the node_modules directory
```ack '^.*(key\s*=){1}.*(key\s*=){1}.*$'```

Comment: This may also occur if you have a duplicate styles key value pair.

Comment: For me, l declared a variable twice in the state array in the constructor method. Unfortunately this error did not cause a crash on iOS but only in Android

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error but with a different keyword

In my case the keyword was declared twice in my css **styles** properties.

```
let styles = StyleSheet.create({
    keyword:{}, 
    keyword:{}
});
```

No crash or warning on iOS but causing a crash on Android.

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same error on v0.49. Spent a lot of time and finally found that there are duplicates in my css declaration:

```
logo: {
    flex:.3,
    height: 120, 
    marginBottom: 10,
},

logo: {
    ...styText,
    marginTop: 10
},
```

just removed the second declaration fixed the error.