# SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'marginTop'.

Tags: react-native

I have an error in my app when it's run in android emulator.
My app works perfectly in iOS, but when I tried to run in Android show this.

Why occurred this?

[image: Application run in Android]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React native Android SyntaxError: Attempted to redefine property 'key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446433/react-native-android-syntaxerror-attempted-to-redefine-property-key)

Comment: You defined marginTop twice.